# Class function doesn't return correct value

Tags: python, class, methods

This is my code:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} x {} = {}'.format(self.height, self.width, self.area)

    def area(self):
        self.area=self.height*self.width
        return self.area


def primarySchool(height, width):
    return str(Rectangle(height, width))
```

For input `height=7` and `width=4`  the output is

```
>>> primarySchool(7, 4):
7 x 4 = <bound method _runjcbjp.<locals>.Rectangle.area of
<__main__._runjcbjp.<locals>.Rectangle object at 0x2b482cd637f0>>
```

instead of `7 x 4 = 28`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`area` is a method of your class, so you have to call it to get the return value (and not the method itself).

But given the fact that you assign to `self.area` inside the method it seems like you want it as "cached" `property` (accessible without calling it explicitly):

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} x {} = {}'.format(self.height, self.width, self.area)

    @property
    def area(self):   # cached version
        try:
            return self._area
        except AttributeError:
            self._area=self.height*self.width
        return self._area


def primarySchool(height, width):
    return str(Rectangle(height, width))

primarySchool(7, 4)
# '7 x 4 = 28'
```

Or as uncached version:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} x {} = {}'.format(self.height, self.width, self.area)

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.height*self.width
```

Or just calculate it in the `__init__` and also set it as attribute:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.area = height * width

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} x {} = {}'.format(self.height, self.width, self.area)
```

Comment: def __init__(self,height, width):
        
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.area=self.height*self.width

Comment: this is more siple solution

Comment: Depends on your use-case. If you want `area` to be dynamic (e.g. it should update when you change `width`) you should make it a property or method :)

Answer (score 3):

In your `Rectangle` class, the `area` member is defined as a method.
As a consequence, `print(self.area)` will give you the representation of that method object, which is that `<...>` thing.

What you want is the *result* of the `area` method, not the method itself.
Therefore, you need to *call* the method, by writing parentheses after its name.

Your code should be:

```
return '{} x {} = {}'.format(self.height, self.width, self.area())
```

---

Additionnally, be careful not to reassign the same name in your method.
In your `area` method, you write:

```
self.area = self.height * self.width
```

As a consequence, after the first call to `instance.area()`, the `area` member will be overwritten, from a function to a number.
Subsequent calls would thus fail, with something like "Int object is not callable".

Comment: Careful here though ... On issuing that statement _again_, things will probably fail because the area method _reassigns_ `self.area` (which is generally a bad idea)

Comment: @mgilson Oh. That's so uncommon I did not even see it. Editing my answer right away.

Comment: class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} x {} = {}'.format(self.height, self.width, self.area)

    def __init__(self,height, width):
        
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.area=self.height*self.width

Comment: i wrote a new init after __str__

Comment: @AvoAsatryan There's no point in writing to `__init__` in a same class; the second would overwrite the first.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to have both a function and property called "area".

Why not simply:

```
def area(self):
    return self.height*self.width
```

Call with:

```
self.area()
```